# Xcode - dyld: Library not loaded error

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm new to MAC and Xcode since I'm a Windows user and I'm really lost. I finally managed to port my game from Windows to MAC and it works in simulator and all but when I launch the executable I get the next error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libSOIL.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myUser/Documents/Cotc/CourierOfTheCrypts/DerivedData/CourierOfTheCrypts/Build/Products/Release/CourierOfTheCrypts
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout
```

I've read a lot of topics about the error but I still don't have a clue about it and how to solve it. All the libraries are copied to the executable folder.

If you need more information please let me know, every bit of help is more than welcome!

EDIT: It turns out /opt/... folder does't exist at all...

Comment: Yeah OSX executables (and dynamic libraries) have the location of the dependent dynamic library hard-coded in during linking.  I assume you've *moved* and not *copied* the library from `/opt/local/lib/` and if you put it back I expect it will work (`image not found` means "file not found").  The solution is use `install_name_tool` after linking to tell the exe/lib where to find the dependent library relative to the exe/lib (using `@executable_path` or `@loader_path`). I also believe Xcode will do that for you, if set-up correctly.

Comment: I tried with the following command:
install_name_tool -change @execitable_path/libSOIL.dylib /opt/local/lib/libSOIL.dylib but it's the same. It doesn't change the search folder.

Comment: It should be `install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libSOIL.dylib @executable_path/libSOIL.dylib /path/to/exe`.  If you are bundling as an app bundle then those `.dylib`s should be in `@executable_path/../Frameworks/...`.

Comment: Oh, is it this way around? Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work and most likely I don't understand correctly. "@executable_path/../Frameworks/" ... what I have is a directory with the executable and libraries, no frameworks map or something. I also don't know what "bundling an app"means. I'm doing a build for OSX. I'm sorry but all this is another world compared to the Windows.

Comment: Folder content: http://1.1m.yt/hL2bTjm.png

Comment: Yeah OSX (and iOS) uses app bundles (`.app` "files") to package applications.  It includes the executable, all dependent libraries and any resources you want to package with it.  Windows and Linux don't have such things (if you discount the limited resources built into Windows exes).  This is the way you will want to go.  If you want to keep it the way you are doing it then the dylib files are simply `@executable_path/libName.dylib`.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help! I have this error now (I guess paths are ok): 
install_name_tool: can't map file: CourierOfTheCrypts (Invalid argument)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 ..... CourierOfTheCrypts = executable

Comment: You are not supplying the correct path to the exe file.  I would have to see the script you are running `install_name_tool` from to help further.

Comment: This is the script ------ install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libSOIL.dylib @executable_path/libName.dylib CourierOfTheCrypts

Comment: Then you are probably not running that script with `Release` as the current working directory.  Do `cd /path/to/Release` and then `/path/to/shellscript.sh`.  Alternatively do: `install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libSOIL.dylib @executable_path/libSOIL.dylib /path/to/Release/CourierOfTheCrypts`

Comment: I don't think I have a script file. I'm adding script directly in the Xcode...
Script screenshot: http://2.1m.yt/U3HPR6.png  or does this create an actually script somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for all the help but <install_name_tool -id @executable_path/libSOIL.dylib "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/libSOIL.dylib"> worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is, to execute the following script for each library:

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/libSOIL.dylib "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/libSOIL.dylib"
```

You enter the script in TARGET settings -> RunScript